# Angular - Loop through response, get a specific value and pass it as a parameter to a func

Tags: angular, typescript

```
0:
description: "desc"
filter: "{equal: '3'}"
filter_name: "desc"
id: 1
pages: [{…}]
1:
description: "descc"
filter: "{equal: '4'}"
filter_name: "descc"
id: 2
pages: [{…}]
```

Above is my response i logged into console. I need to loop through this response and get each filter value. Then, i will pass this values to a function.
Something like this :

```
   this.service.getFilters().subscribe((response : any) => {
          //foreach response
          //get filter value ({equal: '3'})
          function(filter value here)

      })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over response:

```
this.service.getFilters().subscribe((response : any) => {
    response.forEach( item => {
        function(item.filter) // your function that handles each filter separately
    })  
})
```

If you actually need to send all filters together, you can do like this:

```
this.service.getFilters().subscribe((response : any) => {
    let allFilters = [];
    response.forEach( item => {
         allFilters.push(item.filter);
    }) 
    function(allFilters) // your function that handles all filters as an array
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check if this works for you

```
   this.service.getFilters().subscribe((response : any) => {
              for (var json of response) {
                 // console.log(json.filter);
                 function(json.filter)
               }
              //now you will get filter value ({equal: '3'})
          })
```